# How do I use a DLL Interface for USB projector in C++

Tags: c++, dll

I have a piece of hardware called DLP Discovery 4000. Its used for projection of images. It can be programmed by the user. In the hardware's programming guide it has a list of functions that can be accessed in the DLL API interface. The guide says that these functions can be called through C++/C/Java.

I want to be able to use those functions in a C++ program to control the board. But so far I am struggling with exactly how to use the DLL API.

It comes with a software which I installed. The software has a GUI which has limited functions. In addition the software puts a file named D4000_usb.dll in the windows directory. How do I use this .dll file.

Comment: please look in the manual does it give definitions for the functions you can call. Does it mention __declspec anywhere? Or does it mention LoadLibrary, or perhaps a .DEF file? If it does please can you tell us. Are there any sample programs in the manual?

Answer (score 2):

I found this example of someone calling the same dll on the [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/vcgeneral/thread/9b7fb739-9d40-4ede-b2a9-3aed5ae46d03)

**I've annotated it with some helper comments prefixed `// ***` to give you some guidance**

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <iostream>

typedef int (__cdecl *MYPROC)(LPWSTR); 

int main( void ) 
{ 

    HINSTANCE hinstLib; 
    MYPROC ProcAdd; 
    BOOL fFreeResult, fRunTimeLinkSuccess = FALSE; 

    // *** This loads the API DLL into you program

    // Get a handle to the DLL module.
    hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("D4000_usb.dll")); 


    // *** Now we check if it loaded ok - ie we should have a handle to it

    // If the handle is valid, try to get the function address.
    if (hinstLib != NULL) 
    { 

        // *** Now we try and get a handle to the function GetNumDev

        ProcAdd = (MYPROC) GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "GetNumDev"); 

       // *** Now we check if it that worked

        // If the function address is valid, call the function.
        if (NULL != ProcAdd) 
        {
            fRunTimeLinkSuccess = TRUE;

            // *** Now we call the function with a string parameter

            (ProcAdd) (L"Message sent to the DLL function\n"); 


            // *** this is where you need to check if the function call worked
            // *** and this where you need to read the manual to see what it returns

        }


       // *** Now we unload the API dll

        // Free the DLL module.
        fFreeResult = FreeLibrary(hinstLib); 
    } 

    // *** Here is a message to check if the the previous bit worked


    // If unable to call the DLL function, use an alternative.
    if (! fRunTimeLinkSuccess) 
        printf("Message printed from executable\n"); 

return 0;
}
```